# Using enum type keys for a same value in c#

Tags: c#, enums

How can I associate 2 values into a single `enum` type value in a c# application?
For example, I have a `enum` type like this:

```
public enum person 
{ 
    soccerPlayer, 
    tennisPlayer, 
    athlete, 
    coach
}
```

A soccer player and a tennis player are athletes, but a coach is not an  athlete.

If I instance a person, like this:

```
person p = person.soccerPlayer;
```

How do I do this test?

```
if (p == person.athlete)
```

Comment: You should be using classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you would be better served by having a function check to see if the `enum` value is an athlete

```
static bool IsAthlete(person p) { 
  switch (p) { 
    case person.soccerPlayer:
    case person.tennisPlayer:
    case person.athlete:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

Overall though I don't believe an `enum` type serves you well here.  An `enum` is typically used to represent mutually exclusive values (can be A or B but not both) or for bit flag situations.  You could manipulate bit flags to work here but i feel like it isn't the best approach.

This is the type of situation which seems more suitable a full fledged type.

```
class Person { 
  public bool IsAthlete { get; private set; } 
  public bool IsSoccerPlayer { get; private set; } 
  public bool IsTennisPlayer { get; private set; }

  public static readonly TennisPlayer = new Person { 
    IsTennisPlayer = true, 
    IsAthelete = true
  }

  public static readonly SoccerPlayer = new Person { 
    IsSoccerPlayer = true, 
    IsAthelete = true
  }      
}
```